# How to use Device Farm desktop browser session with Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-grid, aws-device-farm

I'm trying to run a Selenium test in Python using Device Farm desktop browser session, but with the lack of resources (official or not), and my lack of knowledge, I can't figure it out.

I used these documentations:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/testgrid/getting-started-migration.html
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage

I installed the GeckoDriver, and ran the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

I saw a web browser appear for about a second.

I then decided to use Device Farm. I setup my AWS env vars, tested the connectivity, and ran the following code:

```
import boto3
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class test_url:
    def setup_method(self, method):
        devicefarm_client = boto3.client("devicefarm", region_name="eu-west-1")
        testgrid_url_response = devicefarm_client.create_test_grid_url(
            projectArn="arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:1234567890:testgrid-project:some-id-string",
            expiresInSeconds=300)
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            "http://www.python.org", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)

    # later, make sure to end your WebDriver session:
    def teardown_method(self, method):
        self.driver.quit()
```

Here's the result:

```
$ pytest -s
====================================================================================== test session starts =======================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.2, pytest-6.0.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/eric/nuage/devicefarm-poc
collected 0 items                                                                                                                                                                                

===================================================================================== no tests ran in 0.07s ======================================================================================
```

I saw nothing happen in the AWS Management Console.

Why did no test run? Shouldn't this code perform an URL test? Shouldn't something happen in the AWS Management Console when I run this?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a few issues with your code.

1. According to the [pytest documentaion](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/) it seems like you need to put your tests into a file starting with the name `test` and to put your tests in methods starting with the word `test` as well. This is why none of your code is executing.
2. The line `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` tries to create a local firefox driver. What you want is a remote driver using the URL that AWS Device Farm provides (which you do at the line `self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://www.python.org", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)`
3. The line `self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://www.python.org", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)` is incorrect. The first argument is supposed to be the URL of the remote endpoint used to execute your tests. In this case, its AWS Device Farm's endpoint that is given in the `CreateTestGridUrl` API response. Selenium is basically just a REST service, so it performs actions via REST calls to an endpoint that tells the driver which actions to perform.
4. AWS Device Farm is currently only in `us-west-2`.

I suggest you go through the pytest, Selenium, and AWS docs again to understand how it all works together. Its not too complex, but it may get confusing if you do not know how all the working parts interact with each other.

---

Here's a "minimal" example with pytest to get you started.

```py
import logging

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import boto3
import pytest

PROJECT_ARN = # Your project ARN

# Currently, AWS Device Farm is only in us-west-2
devicefarm = boto3.client('devicefarm', region_name='us-west-2')
remote_url = devicefarm.create_test_grid_url(
    projectArn=PROJECT_ARN,
    expiresInSeconds=600 # 10 minutes. Increase to longer if needed
)['url']


@pytest.fixture(scope="module") # Specify "module" to reuse the same session
def firefox_driver(request):
    # Start fixture setup
    logging.info("Creating a new session with remote URL: " + remote_url)
    remote_web_driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=remote_url, desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
    logging.info("Created the remote webdriver session: " + remote_web_driver.session_id)
    yield remote_web_driver # Returns driver fixture and waits for tests to run

    logging.info("Teardown the remote webdriver session: " + remote_web_driver.session_id)
    remote_web_driver.quit()
    logging.info("Done tearing down")


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("firefox_driver")
def test_search_in_python_org(firefox_driver):
    driver = firefox_driver
    driver.get("http://www.python.org")
    assert "Python" in driver.title
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys("pycon")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
    # driver.close() // This is done in the fixture instead of here now


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("firefox_driver")
def test_aws_console_title(firefox_driver):
    driver = firefox_driver
    driver.get("https://aws.amazon.com/")
    assert "Amazon Web Services" in driver.title


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```